# Install a New Package Using Puppet 3.1.1 on Solaris 10?

Tags: puppet, solaris-10

I'm pretty new to Puppet and Solaris, and I'm running into an issue installing a package on a Solaris 10 VM using Puppet.  As part of my testing, I wanted to see if I could install Java 6 update 43 on a Solaris 10 VM that only had Java 5 update 24.  Shown below is the issue I'm having and my question.

#### Environment

Solaris Version:  **SunOS 5.10 Generic_142910-17 i386**

Puppet Version:  **3.1.1**

#### Problem

It seems that if a package isn't already installed on Solaris, Puppet won't install it.  Puppet throws the following message:

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Java::Jdk_solaris/Package[SUNWj6cfg]: Could not evaluate: Unable to get information about package SUNWj6cfg because of: No message
```

#### What's Happening

When puppet attempts to install a package on a Solaris machine, it runs the following command before trying to install the package (I saw this when the --debug flag is turned on during  a puppet run):

```
pkginfo -l [whatever the package name is]
```

Example from the puppet agent --test --debug output:

```
Debug: Executing '/usr/bin/pkginfo -l'
Debug: Executing '/usr/bin/pkginfo -l SUNWj6cfg'
Error: /Stage[main]/Java::Jdk_solaris/Package[SUNWj6cfg]: Could not evaluate: Unable to get information about package SUNWj6cfg because of: No message
```

When pkginfo is looking for a package name that doesn't exist (i.e. it isn't installed or the name is wrong, etc), it returns an error, like so:

```
vagrant@puppet-master:[/etc/puppet/manifests] $ pkginfo -l SUNWj6cfg
ERROR: information for "SUNWj6cfg" was not found
```

Okey doke - that makes sense why puppet is getting an error.  Fair enough.  That leads me to these questions:

#### My Question

***Why is Puppet checking to see if the package exists before trying to install it?  Is there a way to bypass this check so Puppet will install a "brand new" package?***

Based on what I'm seeing, it seems like Puppet can only install packages that already exist (i.e. pkginfo can find them) on the server.  That doesn't seem like desirable behavior.  I imagine there are plenty of cases when I'd want to have Puppet install a package that never existed on a Solaris server before.  It's been my experience that if a package already exists, pkgadd will overwrite the package w/a new one.

For example, if I want to install Java 6 update 43 on a Solaris 10 machine that has Java 6 update 21, pkgadd will happily overwrite the existing SUNWj6* packages.  Furthermore, if the SUNWj6* packages don't exist at all (i.e. I completely remove Java 6 via pkgrm), pkgadd will merrily install them.

I'd like to understand why Puppet would behave this way.  Am I totally missing something?  Am I even making sense?

#### Manifests

For completeness (and word count, I guess), here are my puppet manifests (the relevant ones, anyway):

```
/etc/puppet/modules/java/manifests/init.pp:
class java ($distribution, 
            $version, 
            $update
) {
    $class_prefix = $distribution ? { 
        jdk => 'java::jdk',
        jre => 'java::jre',
     }

    case $::operatingsystem {
        'RedHat', 'CentOS': {
            class { "${java::class_prefix}_redhat": 
                version => "${java::version}" 
            } 
            ->
            Class["java"]
        }

        'Solaris': {

            class { "${java::class_prefix}_solaris": 
                version => "${java::version}", 
                update  => "${java::update}",
            } 
            ->
            Class["java"]
        }
    }
}

/etc/puppet/modules/java/manifests/jdk_solaris.pp:
class java::jdk_solaris ($version,
                         $update
) {
    $working_dir        = "/opt/tmp"
    $zip_file_name_32   = "jdk-${version}u${update}-solaris-i586.tar.Z"
    $zip_file_name_64   = "jdk-${version}u${update}-solaris-x64.tar.Z"
    $admin_file         = "java_admin"
    $java_packages      = [ "SUNWj6cfg", 
                            "SUNWj6dev", 
                            "SUNWj6jmp", 
                            "SUNWj6man", 
                            "SUNWj6rt" ]

    file { 
        "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/${java::jdk_solaris::zip_file_name_32}":
        ensure  => file,
        source  => "puppet:///modules/java/${java::jdk_solaris::zip_file_name_32}";

        "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/${java::jdk_solaris::admin_file}":
        ensure  => file,
        source  => "puppet:///modules/java/${java::jdk_solaris::admin_file}";

        "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/SUNWj6cfg/install/checkinstall":
        ensure  => file,
        source  => "puppet:///modules/java/SUNWj6cfg/checkinstall",
        require => Exec["zcat_32"];

        "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/SUNWj6dev/install/checkinstall":
        ensure  => file,
        source  => "puppet:///modules/java/SUNWj6dev/checkinstall",
        require => Exec["zcat_32"];

        "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/SUNWj6jmp/install/checkinstall":
        ensure  => file,
        source  => "puppet:///modules/java/SUNWj6jmp/checkinstall",
        require => Exec["zcat_32"];

        "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/SUNWj6man/install/checkinstall":
        ensure  => file,
        source  => "puppet:///modules/java/SUNWj6man/checkinstall",
        require => Exec["zcat_32"];

        "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/SUNWj6rt/install/checkinstall":
        ensure  => file,
        source  => "puppet:///modules/java/SUNWj6rt/checkinstall",
        require => Exec["zcat_32"];
    }

    file { "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}":
        ensure  => directory,
    }

    exec { "zcat_32":
        cwd     => "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}",
        command => "zcat ${java::jdk_solaris::zip_file_name_32} | tar -xf -",
        creates => [
            "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/SUNWj6cfg",
            "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/SUNWj6dev", 
            "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/SUNWj6jmp", 
            "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/SUNWj6man",
            "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/SUNWj6rt" 
        ],
        path    => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/csw/bin:/opt/csw/sbin",
        require => [
            File["${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}"],
            File["${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/${java::jdk_solaris::zip_file_name_32}"],
        ],
    }                  

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# INSTALL JDK
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    package { $java_packages:
        ensure      => installed,
        source      => "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}",
        adminfile   => "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/${java::jdk_solaris::admin_file}",
        require     => [
            Exec["zcat_32"],
            File[
                "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/SUNWj6cfg/install/checkinstall",
                "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/SUNWj6dev/install/checkinstall",
                "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/SUNWj6jmp/install/checkinstall",
                "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/SUNWj6man/install/checkinstall",
                "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}/SUNWj6rt/install/checkinstall"
            ] # end file array
        ], # end require array
    }

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CLEAN UP AFTER INSTALLATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    exec { "jdk_solaris_cleanup":
        cwd     => "${java::jdk_solaris::working_dir}",
        command => "rm -r ${java::jdk_solaris::admin_file} SUNWj* THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt COPYRIGHT LICENSE README.html ${java::jdk_solaris::zip_file_name_32}",
        path    => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/csw/bin:/opt/csw/sbin",
        require => Package[$java_packages],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the [same question](https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/1230/install-a-new-package-using-puppet-311-on-solaris-10/) on ask.puppetlabs.com, and here is the answer I received:

> How should puppet know, if a package is brand-new? Puppet has to check
>   if the package is already installed.
>
> But this looks like a recent regression bug in the `sun` package
>   provider because having a short glance at it puppet neither checks the
>   returncode of the `pkginfo` command, nor does it parse the output for
>   known error messages.
>
> So if you can file a bug at projects.puppetlabs.com/issues, I'll
>   try to look at the issue when I come home. When you file a bug, please
>   drop the ticket number as a comment.

I have created ticket [20629](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/20629) with the Puppet Labs folks to track this issue.